# 2010 Powershell Taxonomy Term Store issues

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, managed-metadata, term-store

My file being uploaded is initiated below, I call $spFile.Item which is a SPListItem to call    `setFieldValue($spFile.Item,$term)`

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.URL + "/" + $File.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteURL
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $siteURL
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$lobField = $spSite.RootWeb.Fields["Lines of Business"] 
$termStoreID = $lobField.SspId
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores[$termStoreID]
$termStore.get_Groups() | foreach{if($_.Name -eq "Corporate Store"){$termGroup = $_}}
$termGroup.get_TermSets() | foreach{if($_.Name -eq "Lines of Business"){$lobTermSet = $_}}
$lobTermCollection = $lobTermSet.GetAllTerms()
$lobTermCollection.GetEnumerator() | foreach{if($_.Name -eq $lineofbusiness){[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Term]$lobTerm = $_}}
$lobField.SetFieldValue($spFile.item,$lobTerm)
```

It's a big mess, but my previous method of doing the same thing in 2013 did not work at all. I always get the error

```
SetFieldValue : Exception calling "SetFieldValue" with "2" argument(s): "The given guid does not exist in the term store"

At line:1 char:24
+ $lobField.SetFieldValue <<<< ($spFile.Item,$lobTerm)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

How can I set the managed metadata properly for this file I am uploading to a document library on 2010? I have only worked with 2013 before.

I did [what this guy said](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/49ca97ba-664e-4e55-9387-a48c606b945f/powershell-wont-update-value-in-managed-metadata-field-in-document-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) and it didn't work either I should add. Even properly getting the field from the file I add doesn't work. There seems to be a disconnect between the taxonomysession/termstore I am retrieving and the real one since it does not recognize terms I know are in the termset by string value

Comment: I should also note that I used PowerGUI & Management Shell both in Admin Mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never got formally introduced to sharepoint, but the error seems trivial to me.

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]$spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.URL + "/" + $File.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteURL
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $siteURL
```

### My two changes were

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$lobField = $spFile.Item.Fields["Lines of Business"]
```

and

```
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
```

---

```
termStore.get_Groups() | foreach{if($_.Name -eq "Corporate Store"){$termGroup = $_}}
$termGroup.get_TermSets() | foreach{if($_.Name -eq "Lines of Business"){$lobTermSet = $_}}
$lobTermCollection = $lobTermSet.GetAllTerms()
$lobTermCollection.GetEnumerator() | foreach{if($_.Name -eq $lineofbusiness){[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Term]$lobTerm = $_}}
$lobField.SetFieldValue($spFile.item,$lobTerm)
```

But I checked the GUID of the termstore called by string/hash and called by $lobField.sspid and they were the same! Oh well. also the GUID of the $lobField TaxField was the same.

If someone can explain that i will mark it as correct